# Django - unique ids for all instances of subclasses of a class?

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

I'm sorry I can't think of a better way to describe the question in the title, please feel free to edit if you can :)

My problem is this: In Django I have an abstract class (subclassing models.Model) called Item. I then have a bunch of subclasses of Item, for instance FoodItem, BookItem, ToyItem... I decided on this structure because every Item has mostly the same fields (Item name, etc...) but the usage will be different depending on what type it is.

I would like every Item however to have a unique identifier so that I can easily reference it. Since each subclass is its own database table, I don't think I can use primary keys. How can I get every Item to have a unique id, instead of every FoodItem having unique ids but maybe overlapping with the BookItems etc... Finally, when I get an Item by its id, is there an elegant way to tell what item type it is?

I am open to doing this differently if there is a better way. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of the Base/Child model relationship, Just declare a `ForeignKey` to the item type. That way you are guaranteed unique IDs

Comment: Oh wow, good idea. Shouldn't I use OneToOne though since each FoodItem, BookItem etc will correspond to one Item?

Comment: Oh. I was thinking categories rather than items. You are right. You can use OneToOne.

Comment: Can you please post that as an answer? It's a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd *strongly* recommend using [django-typed-models](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-typed-models) ([github](https://github.com/craigds/django-typed-models)). It exists to solve your problem (many subclasses with mostly identical fields but different behaviour) and you get unique primary keys for free.

From the wiki page:

> **Features**
>
> - Automatic downcasting of models from querysets.
> - All models subclassing a common base are stored in the same table
> - object types are stored in a 'type' field in the database
> - No extra queries or joins to retrieve multiple types